# Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the auto-configuration report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled. using netbeans/ Spring

Tags: mysql, netbeans, dependencies

I'm working on team with some members, so I'm the only one that having this problem, it worked in 5 computers but I have the problem when I want to build the project: this is my app properties code:

```
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/Test
spring.datasource.username = root   
spring.datasource.password = 

# Keep the connection alive if idle for a long time (needed in production)
spring.datasource.testWhileIdle = true
spring.datasource.validationQuery = SELECT 1

# Show or not log for each sql query
spring.jpa.show-sql = true

# Hibernate ddl auto (create, create-drop, update)
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update

# Naming strategy
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming-strategy = org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy

# Use spring.jpa.properties.* for Hibernate native properties (the prefix is
# stripped before adding them to the entity manager)

# The SQL dialect makes Hibernate generate better SQL for the chosen database
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
```

My pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.project.jpa</groupId>
    <artifactId>coaching_back_end</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>coaching_back_end</name>
    <description>Coaching project</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.10.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
                dependency>
                    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>

                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                    <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
                </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
                <dependency>
                        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
                        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
                </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

The log having the error:

```
:: Spring Boot ::       (v1.5.10.RELEASE)

2018-02-18 15:23:07.594  INFO 9582 --- [           main] c.p.j.coaching.CoachingApplicationTests  : Starting CoachingApplicationTests on Gate11.local with PID 9582 (started by gate11 in /Users/gate11/Desktop/coachinglocal/coaching/coaching_back_end)
2018-02-18 15:23:07.596  INFO 9582 --- [           main] c.p.j.coaching.CoachingApplicationTests  : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2018-02-18 15:23:07.702  INFO 9582 --- [           main] o.s.w.c.s.GenericWebApplicationContext   : Refreshing org.springframework.web.context.support.GenericWebApplicationContext@503d687a: startup date [Sun Feb 18 15:23:07 CET 2018]; root of context hierarchy
2018-02-18 15:23:10.215  INFO 9582 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$291bf4b3] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2018-02-18 15:23:11.703  INFO 9582 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Building JPA container EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2018-02-18 15:23:11.748  INFO 9582 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: default
    ...]
2018-02-18 15:23:12.026  INFO 9582 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.0.12.Final}
2018-02-18 15:23:12.029  INFO 9582 --- [           main] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
2018-02-18 15:23:12.032  INFO 9582 --- [           main] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
2018-02-18 15:23:12.128  INFO 9582 --- [           main] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.1.Final}
2018-02-18 15:23:12.474  INFO 9582 --- [           main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
2018-02-18 15:23:13.821  INFO 9582 --- [           main] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate  : HHH000228: Running hbm2ddl schema update
2018-02-18 15:23:13.866  WARN 9582 --- [           main] o.s.w.c.s.GenericWebApplicationContext   : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
2018-02-18 15:23:13.885  INFO 9582 --- [           main] utoConfigurationReportLoggingInitializer : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the auto-configuration report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2018-02-18 15:23:13.943 ERROR 9582 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1628) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1080) ~[spring-context-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:857) ~[spring-context-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:543) ~[spring-context-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693) ~[spring-boot-1.5.10.RELEASE.jar:1.5.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360) ~[spring-boot-1.5.10.RELEASE.jar:1.5.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303) ~[spring-boot-1.5.10.RELEASE.jar:1.5.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:120) [spring-boot-test-1.5.10.RELEASE.jar:1.5.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:98) [spring-test-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:116) [spring-test-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:83) [spring-test-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.setUpRequestContextIfNecessary(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:189) [spring-test-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:131) [spring-test-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:230) [spring-test-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:228) [spring-test-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:287) [spring-test-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289) [spring-test-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:247) [spring-test-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:94) [spring-test-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61) [spring-test-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70) [spring-test-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:191) [spring-test-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:283) [surefire-junit4-2.18.1.jar:2.18.1]
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeWithRerun(JUnit4Provider.java:173) [surefire-junit4-2.18.1.jar:2.18.1]
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:153) [surefire-junit4-2.18.1.jar:2.18.1]
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:128) [surefire-junit4-2.18.1.jar:2.18.1]
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.invokeProviderInSameClassLoader(ForkedBooter.java:203) [surefire-booter-2.18.1.jar:2.18.1]
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:155) [surefire-booter-2.18.1.jar:2.18.1]
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:103) [surefire-booter-2.18.1.jar:2.18.1]
```

I tried many suggestions from here in the forum but didn't work, I tried to add dependencies In pom.xml but still didn't work.
If it can be helpful, I'm using a MySql server in localhost, using a Mac.
Thanks

Comment: please check in mysql DB "Test" Schema is present or not. if It is not present create that schema and re-run you application.

Comment: What is check your mysql database user and password.?

Comment: @DipakThoke I don't have a problem with user and password, it's just a table to test I have no schema

Answer (score 0):

According to your application.properties file I can see you missed following things:

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name = com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.database = MYSQL
```

And other issue in your properties file is following

> `# Keep the connection alive if idle for a long time (needed in  production)`
>
> `spring.datasource.testWhileIdle = true`
>
> `spring.datasource.validationQuery = SELECT 1`

Here to have effect , you need to specify in follwoing way:

```
spring.datasource.tomcat.testWhileIdle = true
spring.datasource.tomcat.validationQuery = SELECT 1
```